# Ignore part of db sets migration in entity framework code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a question, having simple context:

```
    public DbSet<Current> Currents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationFile> ApplicationFile { get; set; }

    private readonly string dbPath;

    public SqliteContext(string filePath)
    {
        dbPath = filePath;
    }

    public SqliteContext()
    {
        dbPath = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\application.db";
        ApplicationFileMigration();
    }

    private void ApplicationFileMigration()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($@"Data Source={dbPath}");
    }
```

I want to create migration only on ApplicationFile entity and ignore Currents and Events, I know it is possible to do it with separate context, but is it possible in a single context, some kind of ignore annotation or default configuration?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do that... there might be a better way to approach the actual problem.

Comment: 2 of those are imported sqlite files and do not need to be migrated, Application file is a internal db that i want to create for application purposes

Comment: Re-reading your comment, it sounds like the two pre-existing files would need a different connection string? Then my answer would be wrong, I assumed you work on one DB and you just have pre-existing tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following: [Entity Framework Code First Migrations with an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx)

The standard way to work with migrations would be, to first create your context **only** with the existing model. Then add a migration where actual changes are ignored (as per step 3 in linked article)

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
Update-Database
```

This will create the migration history table and will mark the current model as mapped.

Then add the additional entities that you really want to migrate as your second migration.

So in your case, first remove `ApplicationFile` for the initial migration, then re-add it and create a second migration. It will only create the DDL SQL for `ApplicationFile`, not for the other entities